# Теория вероятности, дисперсии

Tags: javascript, бот, функциональное-программирование

> ТВ - теория вероятности

Идея заключается в том, что есть определенный скрипт-обертка, если можно так назвать. И нужно додумать логику работы именно функционала скрипта.

И тут заключается весь смысл, в ТВ. Есть сайт, где есть благоприятные и неблагоприятные события, они рандомом выпадают события. И насколько я понимаю, нужно по формуле описать ТВ + какое-то количество событий, по которому может строиться расчёт. И это описывается все в function().

Затем выставляем if'ы трехуровневый, в каких моментах он будет смотреть сколько неблагоприятных событий, чтобы потом по ТВ начал активироваться действие, и попадать в благоприятные события.

Вопрос! Как лучше всего прописать ТВ в скрипте? Я просто не уверен, правильно ли я понимаю.

Comment: в чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: Оу, извиняюсь, забыл дописать) Сейчас отредактирую.

Comment: вот по объяснению вообще непонятно что у тебя есть и что ты хочешь в итоге.

Comment: Отбросим что есть, я хочу спросить о том, как лучше всего описать теорию вероятности событий в скрипте, чтобы создать 3-хуровневую if, где в каждом if будет описаны количество считываемых неблагоприятных событий, то есть в 1 if(50 неблагоприятных), то переходим к 2 if(15 неблагоприятных), то переходим к 3 if(5 неблагоприятных). И выстраивать более точную картину, когда будет все же благоприятные события, чтобы скрипт начинал действовать.

Comment: чтобы описать _теорию вероятности_, нужно сначала определиться вероятность чего ты хочешь найти. По твоему пояснению этого не ясно

Comment: Допустим У нас есть А и Б, А - красное, Б - зеленое, я хочу узнать по теории вероятности, когда приблизительно будут следующий Б-шаг. 
http://screenshot.su/img/fe/62/fb/fe62fbbfe7cb3d1a16003bad3906e00a.jpg